# Add AWS Cognito SignIn/ SignUp Feature on Squarespace Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, squarespace

We have a website hosted on Squarespace. We want to add sign-in/sign-up feature to our website using AWS Cognito.The Website supports our Mobile App that uses AWS Cognito User Pool. How can we integrate AWS Cognito in our Squarespace WebPage? What other methods might work to accomplish this?

There is no specific documentation available on Squarespace regarding third party integrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [you can only add "client-side code"](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815928-Adding-custom-code-to-your-site) to a Squarespace site, and not server-side code, you can only integrate with third-party services if it A) it is within their rather limited and internally-curated list of [extensions](https://www.squarespace.com/extensions/home) or B) it can be done entirely via JavaScript on the front-end.

> You can't add server-side code
>
> Server-side code is handled by a server, not by a browser, and
> includes:
> PHP, Ruby, Ruby on Rails, SQL

So you'd have to integrate the service using entirely client-side code, most likely using the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/), if that is possible. See the client-side authentication flow section [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-client-side-authentication-flow). The "Implicit grant" section [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/) may also be applicable.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brandon. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried this approach getting Uncaught ReferenceError: AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined. Don't know whats going wrong

Comment: BrowserScript approach seems to work with SquareSpace + AWS Cognito. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm interested in trying this out, but struggling to envisage what the solution looks like. Do you have a code snippet to show how this would work?